# How to select all elements that are not of a class within an id css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

this is the current css I am using however it sets the class i dont want set ad display none as display none aswell.

```
#parent :not(.firstchild) {
                 display:none;
             }
```

and here is the html

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="firstchild"></div>  <----- I dont want this set to display none
    <div class="secondchild"></div><----- I want this set to display none
     <div class="thirdchild"></div><----- I want this set to display none
</div>
```

however it sets all to display:none????.

Some help would be awesome :)

Comment: `#parent *:not(.firstchild)` should work.

Comment: Looks like it works to me - http://jsfiddle.net/pqdg9sLc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#parent div:not(:first-child) {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="firstchild">im the first</div> 
  <div class="secondchild">im teh second</div>
  <div class="thirdchild">im the third</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `div class="firstchild"` but not(:first-child).  **firstchild** & **first-child** both are not same.is it typo?

Comment: oh ... replaced ":" with "."

Comment: To rephrase @Pitchers' comment: why are you using the `:first-child` pseudo-class and not the `.firstchild` class selector?

Comment: i made the assumption that OP wanted only the first child of the div to show and that the classes was OP's way of approaching the problem. if i misunderstood the task and `.firstchild` is not actually the first child of the `#parent`, then i apologize for jumping to conclusions

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this way, that I think that is a workaround:

```
#parent div {
  display: none;
}

#parent div.firstchild {
  display: initial;
}
```

Hope it helps.